# resubmit a form using php or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

good day,

i want to resubmit a form using php or jquery.

the form will upload a file and to prevent the user from searching for the file and uploading it again and submitting the form, I want them to be able to just resubmit the form to process the file again. the purpose of this is that after uploading the file my code would show some data from the database but what if you have added some new data after you uploaded the file, so the prevent the user from moving back to step 1, I want them to just resubmit the form.

is this possible and how would i go with this?

thank you :)

Comment: $('#form_id').submit();

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by: `to prevent the user from searching for the file` and `but what if you have added some new data after you uploaded the file`.  The situation is just not clear.  Please try to explain a bit further.